# How to set maximum calculation time in matlab (without activating Simulink)

Tags: matlab, execution, timing

I'm doing simulation in Matlab where some data from the simulation are obtained by executing **another software**. The idea is when the calculation time is beyond a limit the data from the simulation will not be accepted. How to set a maximum calculation time to automatically stop this unnecessary calculation? **I don't use Simulink at the moment.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try investigating the use of tic, toc commands if you are doing loop-styled calculations. e.g. at the very start of the calculation:

```
tic;
```

just before end of each loop:

```
if (toc>60)   %//However many seconds you want
    break;
end
```

This might not be useful if you don't have loop-style calculations you have direct access to.